# Java SQLite org.sqlite.JDBC classpath broken?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, sqlitejdbc

I stumbled upon a weird error while using JDBC sqlite with `org.sqlite.JDBC`
my code compiles and runs fine on Windows.
But when I tried moving it to Ubuntu it started showing this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
        at mall.SQLiteJDBC.<init>(SQLiteJDBC.java:27)
        at mall.AllegroReader.<init>(AllegroReader.java:33)
        at mall.Mall.main(Mall.java:31)
```

I'm running it with `java -classpath "sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" -jar Mall.jar"` and `java -classpath "sqlite-jdbc4-3.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar" -jar Mall.jar`
with both versions in the same directory as my jar and I've tried a dozen different options specifying classpath and it behaves exactly the same. I tried openjdk and oracle jdk.
I tried rebuilding it on Ubuntu, changing ant .xmls, changing paths, etc.

I have no idea what is going on. Pls help.

Here is what happens inside my dist directory:

```
work1@workwork:/var/www/mall/dist$ ls
mall.db  Mall.jar  Mall.jar.old  sqlite-jdbc-3.8.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

work1@workwork:/var/www/mall/dist$ java -classpath "sqlite-jdbc-3.8.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:Mall.jar" Mall
Error: Could not find or load main class Mall
```

Comment: The classpath is ignored when you use `-jar`.

You have to either include the dependencies in the jar (or at least have the jar manifest point to them), or run it with `-classpath sqlite.jar:Mall.jar the.main.class`

Comment: After trying about a dozen combinations finally this worked

`java -classpath "sqlite-jdbc-3.8.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:Mall.jar" Mall.main` 

YAY! Thanks! (the main class was inside Mall.java) - if it was the answer I would mark it as solved :)

Comment: damn... I lost it again... :( I'm in dist directory... issuing `java -classpath "sqlite-jdbc-3.8.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:Mall.jar" Mall.main` gives me `Error: Could not find or load main class Mall.main`. all files are there, my main class comes from Mall.java -> Mall.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classpath is ignored when you use `-jar`.

You have to either include the dependencies in the jar (or at least have the jar manifest point to them), or run it with `-classpath sqlite.jar:Mall.jar the.main.class`.

> Error: Could not find or load main class Mall.main. all files are there, 
>   my main class comes from `Mall.java` and is in `mall` package which
>   compiles to `Mall.jar`

So the correct command line is:

```
java -classpath "sqlite-jdbc-3.8.4.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:Mall.jar" mall.Mall
```

---

OP findings

to view the classes in jar use `jar tf Mall.jar` - from this I got `mall/Mall.class` meaning my class containing main was `mall.Mall`

it showed

mall/Mall.class

so I should have used mall.Mall as the class to run (instead of pulling my hair)

Answer (score 0):

After spending over 6 hours total with many failed attempts at running "portable" jar package using classpath and whatnot, after having tried OneJar and jarjar to no avail (ended up with `Class file too large!`) I decided to write the offending piece of code in PHP.

It proved to be more portable than Java in my case.